# Azure logic apps - Schedulers

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, job-scheduling

I have a job which need to be scheduled daily at 8am, 9am and every 15min from 10am to 4pm how can I schedule this job on azure logic apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to schedule individual time in logic app.

In order to work through your requirement :

You could have the logic app triggered (scheduled) for every 15 minutes. In the logic app flow you could extract the time.

```
formatDateTime(utcNow(),"HH:mm")
```

You could compare with your schedule and run the job if the conditions met.

---

**Pseudo Logic**

if time is 8:00 AM or if time is 9:00 AM

- **Yes**, set the flag (a boolean variable)  to **True**
- **No**, check if the time is between 10 AM to 4 PM

  - **Yes** , Set the flag to **true**
  - **No** ,Set the flag to **false**

if the flag is true run the job else, do nothing.

Comment: Please consider accepting this solution if it had helped :)
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work